# Limit width of element or clip it to another element

Tags: html, css

I'm builing like family tree, and i have i little bit problem.

I use ::before pseudo-elements as lines to connect persons. The border lines (reds on the pictures) are meant to be less than standart. But element `<li>` is different by the width, and i don't know how to trim ::before line to person.
I don't really well know how to explain so: i basicly need trim red lines to nearest person vertical line, but every red line is different
Oh, by the way, i'm using Django framework (it's about {% static ... %})
And i use LESS preprocessor

HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul class="generation gen_1">
        <li>
            <!--<div class="couple">
                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
            </div>-->
            <div class="couple">
                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="generation gen_2">
                <li>
                    <div class="couple">
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="generation gen_3">
                        <li>
                            <div class="couple">
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="couple">
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="couple">
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="couple">
                        <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                        <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="generation gen_3">
                        <li>
                            <div class="couple">
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="couple">
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="generation gen_4">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="couple">
                                        <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                        <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="generation gen_5">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="couple">
                                                <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                                <a href="#"><div class="person married spouse"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><div class="person married child"><img src="{% static 'main/img/SVG/person.svg' %}" alt=""></div></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}

.couple{
  display: flex;
}

.person {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: @back;
  img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #AF0404;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }
}
.child{
  position: relative;
  &::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid white;
    height:25px;
    left:25px;
    top:-25px;
  }
}

.couple{
  position: relative;
  &::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid white;
    height: 65px;
    left:50%;
    bottom:-25%;
  }
}

.generation{
  position: relative;
}

.generation > li{
  &::before{
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    top:-6px;
  }
}
.generation > li:first-child{
  &::before{
      border:1px solid red;
      left:25%;
  }
}

.gen_1 > li:first-child{
  &::before{
    border: 0;
  }
}

.spouse{
  position: relative;
  &::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid white;
    width: 75%;
    right:100%;
    top:50%;
    z-index:3;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey friend - any way you can provide a markup image of what you are trying to accomplish to give us a better understanding of the objective?

Comment: @KameronMayers i'm trying to limit the red lines (which on the left corners) to nearest person's vertical line, like on this node: https://prnt.sc/1t46usn
But all red lines have different width (because childern's variaty), and i don't know how to trim red lines to nearest person node (vertical line up of person). 

Sorry, i know well know how to explain, plus english is not my native launguage